# Swift project crashing with Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

It looks like a bad memory access, like trying to access an object that does not exist. I tried using NSZombie to see if something came up, as far as I could tell nothing did. It is crashing at the declaration for the app delegate.

AppDelegate.swift

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Bool
{
    // Override point for customization after app launches
    Parse.setApplicationId("removed on purpose", clientKey: "removed on purpose")
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool
{
    return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, withSession: PFFacebookUtils.session())

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)
{
    FBAppCall.handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession(PFFacebookUtils.session())
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication)
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication)
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication)
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

DashboardViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController
{
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view
}

}
```

Using breakpoints I have determined that it is not even getting past the class declaration for the app delegate. I tried checking all of the classes in my Main.storyboard file as well to make sure everything was linked properly, again as far as I can tell it is.

Comment: Is this all of your code?  I'm not a Swift expert, but we probably need more.

Comment: I didn't put the rest of the code in because it did not seem relevant. The program does not run past the line class AppDelegate... I can post the rest if you think it is relevant

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's relevant.

Comment: The simulator only shows a black screen after the error is thrown. I am using a storyboard file as well if that helps. One simple view with navigation bar, one button with an action segue to pull up another view. Beyond that there is nothing going on

Comment: Solved** If you look at the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function I forgot the `!` for the optionals after all the parameters and the last parameter should actually be an `NSDictionary!`. Feel rather dumb that I missed that >.<

Comment: I'm seeing this with an empty method body (only `return true`) in Xcode 7 with iOS 9. The signature includes a `?` instead of `!`, as the file template includes, as well as the autocomplete suggests. I get a warning otherwise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today. As of Xcode 6 beta 6 the auto complete suggests:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Bool {}
```

This crashes at startup with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and a blank screen.

As soon as an `!` is added to the last argument, everything works fine:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Bool {}
```

In [current documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) the `!` is missing as well:

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Bool
```

Comment: I am glad somebody else noticed this as well. I also am curious why they would auto complete with an AnyObject! parameter when it is expecting an NSDictionary of launchOptions anyway. Hopefully this can help some other people who may have run into this problem!

Comment: Xcode 7 includes a `?` instead of `!` and I'm still getting this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Works with Xcode 6.1:

Try

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground(launchOptions, block: nil)
```

instead of

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions()
```

Comment: `PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions()` works just fine. Just used it in a project. You need to make sure that in your [AppName]-Bridging-Header.h file that you add `#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>` after you double check that it should work just fine

Comment: @SamG No, I have just tested and what you say does not work in the last version of the iOS Parse API, because of the absence of this method. But maybe it can work in the previous versions of iOS Parse API.

Comment: Otherwise (no link with my previous comment) there is a mistake in your StackOverflow description's profile: "I really enjoy C# and the .Net framework as well as Swift, Apple's new programming language, as they are more similar than Objective-C and C#." It should rather be something like that: "I really enjoy the .Net framework and Swift (Apple's new programming language) as they are more similar than Objective-C."

Answer (score 0):

*Solution from OP.*

Problem solved by fixing the code as below.

In all method signatures, replace:

```
application: UIApplication
```

with:

```
application: UIApplication!
```

And in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, replace:

```
launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]
```

with:

```
launchOptions: NSDictionary!
```